# How do I perform rolling aggregate with lag in terms of time?

Tags: pandas

I would like to perform the task called rolling aggregate with lag... Starting with this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]},
                   index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')])
 
    B
2013-01-01 09:00:00     0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02     1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03     2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05     NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:06     4.0
```

I would need to perform

```
df.rolling("3s excluding first 1s").max() # or more precisely df.rolling("(-3s,-1s]").max() 
#closed on -1s, open on -3s
```

My real application involved extremely large dataframe where timestamp also had no constant interval and I also had id. So my real application is really groupby rolling aggregate with lag. (shift approach/merge_as_of approach won't work in my case...)

The expected result is

```
    B
2013-01-01 09:00:00     NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:02     0.0 
2013-01-01 09:00:03     1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05     2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:06     NaN
```

Comment: can you define `rolling aggregation with lag` clearer?

Comment: `shift approach/merge_as_of approach won't work in my case.` why not? If your current provided data doesn't accurately represent the struggles of working with your real dataset, it may be a good idea to update your example to be more representative.